# audio stopped working sudden in a .avi file

Tags: 11.04, sound

I watched some tv that is in a .avi file yesterday everything worked fine but this morning (and now) the audio stops working after 5 seconds and the video gets jumpy.

Info, 11.04, asus 1201n, both vlc and movie player has the error.

Stefano Palazzo helped with this. `sudo gedit /var/log/apt/history.log` .

this update was the last one.

`Start-Date: 2011-06-21  00:43:42
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: indicator-multiload:amd64 (0.2-0+31~6~15~natty1, 0.2-0+31~7~15~natty1)
End-Date: 2011-06-21  00:43:55`

Comment: Open Synaptic, File -> History. This should tell you what was updated yesterday.

Comment: I do all my updates by typing `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` and that isn't shown there, (my last update is from 3 weeks ago.)

Comment: you can check out `/var/log/apt/history.log` as well

Comment: Please check how much resources does indicator-multiload use if you use it.

Comment: not all of it, I have free ram (45% used) and free cpu (about 35% used).

Comment: Did you try reinstalling pulseaudio?

Comment: Does `alsactl restore` solves your issue?

Comment: Still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Actually not, it was probably a bug, that got fixed.

Comment: Then, shall 10kers cast delete votes?